# PowerShell Copy Files in Source Folder to Matching Destination Fails With Destination Value

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy files in one folder to another folder. Files should go in the same folder structure under their parent folders. For example,
C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Alpha\File1.txt
should go to
C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Beta\File1.txt

It fails in the last line where I specify the Destination value in a Copy-Item:

```
$sourcedir = "C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Alpha"
$localdir = "C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Beta"

# Assumes folders are established by other processes
$sourceContents = Get-ChildItem $sourcedir -Recurse | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }
$localContents = Get-ChildItem $localdir | Where-Object { -not $_.PsIsContainer }

Compare-Object $sourceContents $localContents -Property Name,Length,LastWriteTime -PassThru | 
    Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="} | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        Write-Output $_.FullName, $_.Name;
        Write-Output $localdir;
        $a = Join-Path $localdir $_.FullName.SubString($sourcedir.Length);
        Write-Output $a;
        Write-Output $_;
        # Write-Outputs are just to see what's going on
        # Works as expected up until here
        Copy-Item $_ -Destination "$a"
    }
```

I get, in this case, an error saying, "Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Boss\File1.txt because it does not exist."

I have tried a number of things and ended up with the above trying different ways to feed the Destination value.

When I accomplish this, the source needs to become a network share. I thought of using Robocopy early on, but I need to migrate this yet again to using a URL for the source.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I program in C# .NET but I've always found PowerShell a challenge to learn.

---

Using Theo's example, I simplified my code to the following. Note that I moved the folders to one outside of the Users and not in any synchronised folder.

```sh
$sourcedir = "C:\Unsynchronised\Alpha"
$localdir = "C:\Unsynchronised\Beta"
# I kept the "local" because I would like to use this for server-client some day

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $localDirPath = Join-Path -Path $localdir -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourcedir.Length)
    $localDirFile = Join-Path -Path $localDirPath -ChildPath $_.Name

    Write-Output $_.DirectoryName
    Write-Output $localDirPath
    Write-Output $localDirFile
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination %localDirPath
}
```

Output gives...

```
C:\Unsynchronised\Alpha
C:\Unsynchronised\Beta\
C:\Unsynchronised\Beta\TestFile.txt
C:\Unsynchronised\Alpha\Folder1
C:\Unsynchronised\Beta\Folder1
C:\Unsynchronised\Beta\Folder1\Subfile_1_1.txt
```

Files in Beta remain unchanged despite newer ones of the same name in Alpha.

Comment: That error is talking about the source file, not the destination.  Is that the real error message or did you clean it up because I'm not seeing how you are getting filename `C:\Users\Boss\File1.txt` from source directory of `C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Alpha`

Comment: @Daniel: Yes and No. Yes, I changed the real folder, "Work," to "Boss" so that people would know it was a folder under Users for an individual. I just happen to have named the account "Work." No, that is the result. I am working in PowerShell from C:\Users\Work, so that is where I think it is trying to put the file. It is ignoring the value in $a and putting the file in the working directory, or attempting to. (Edit: I am adjusting the code now to see if it works, but I cannot rely on the script running from the root of where I need the files to go.)

Comment: Ok.  What I was trying to say though is that that error message is given when it can't find the file being copied.  Message given when destination cannot be found is `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\temp\lkdsffsdf\'`

Comment: Also, if you give `Copy-Item` a destination, in this case `$a` it is not going to try and copy the file to the working directory unless the destination you give it is null.  You note in your script that your `$a` variable contains the expected destination with note "Works as expected up until here" so destination will be whatever is contained in $a.  By the way, it's unnecessary to have the quotes around $a

Comment: About the quotation marks, yes, I think it was one of those trails I did and they got left behind, or a try-anything attempt, in case I got the syntax wrong.

Comment: Regarding the -Destination: I thought that, too, but when trying to think of the problem, it seemed easier to assume the -Destination value is not being acknowledged or used, rather than indicate a problem with the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `Compare-Object` on this, but an `if()` condition inside a simple loop to test if a file already exists in the destination path and if not, copy it from the source path, creating subfolders where needed:

```
$sourcedir   = "C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Alpha"
$destination = "C:\Users\Boss\One\Two\Beta"

# get a string array of files already in the destination path (FullNames only)
$existingFiles = (Get-ChildItem -Path $destination -Recurse -File).FullName

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourcedir.Length)
    $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath $_.Name
    # test if the file is not already present in the destination
    if ($existingFiles -notcontains $targetFile) {
        # create the destination subfolder path if this does not yet exist
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath
    }
}
```

---

Since your question did not show you want to only copy files that are not already present in the destination, but also **newer** versions of existing files, please see the edited version below:

```
$sourcedir   = 'C:\Unsynchronised\Alpha'
$destination = 'C:\Unsynchronised\Beta'

Get-ChildItem -Path $sourcedir -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    $targetPath = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.DirectoryName.Substring($sourcedir.Length)
    $targetFile = Join-Path -Path $targetPath -ChildPath $_.Name
    # test if the file is not already present in the destination
    $existingFile = Get-Item -Path $targetFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    # if there is no such file or that file is older than the one we have in the source directory
    if (!$existingFile -or $_.LastWriteTime -gt $existingFile.LastWriteTime) {
        # create the destination subfolder path if this does not yet exist
        $null = New-Item -Path $targetPath -ItemType Directory -Force
        $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $targetPath -Force
    }
}
```

And knowing this, why not use robocopy for it?

Something like

```
robocopy.exe $sourcedir $destination /S /XO /COPYALL /R:0 /W:0
```

where

```
/S       Do not copy empty directories
/XO      Excludes older files (do not overwrite existing files that are newer in the destination)
/COPYALL Copy ALL file info
/R:0     Number of retries on failures (default 1 million)
/W:0     Wait time between retries in seconds (default is 30 seconds)
```

Comment: This didn't work, though I do not believe, at first, that it is anything wrong with what you have provided. This was the algorithm I was next going to try, and yours is probably more elegant that mine would have been. I'll edit my OP with my version of this attempt as an (unsuccessful) Answer so you can see clearly. I modified your code to remove the if( ). I thought I'd take that out of the equation and just copy the files in any case, and it still did not. No error message this time, though. I also moved the folders to a folder off the root of C:\.

Comment: @em_sys Please see my edited version that also copies files if they are newer than what is already in the destination

Comment: I tried Robocopy yesterday, and it did not work from PS. I tried it from cmd, and it did work. I started work today with an idea to change the settings for the Set-ExecutionPolicy. I also tried your

Comment: (grrr...this is dumb editor with max 5min) I thought I indicated that I wanted newer files by including the LastWriteTime in my Compare-Object statement. Sorry for the confusion. So today, I started work with an idea to change the settings for the Set-ExecutionPolicy. I also tried your new code, and it worked. But then again, I tried my own code and it worked. So then I thought maybe it was indeed the Set-ExecutionPolicy, so I rebooted my computer and tried another trial. It worked with my code and yesterday's policy. I'm not sure why everything is working today, but your code helped, Theo.